# How count same columns from few tables in one SQL query

Tags: sql

I have five tables, TDetective, TMonths, TProduct1, TProduct2 and TProduct3. I want to have a result set with four columns:

- first is Detective name
- second is count - how many TProduct1 are assigned to this Detective in special months
- third is count - how many TProduct2 are assigned to this Detective in special months
- and fourth is count - how many TProduct3 are assigned to this Detective in special months.

Please help me.

TDetective

```
    |id     |
    |Detective|
```

TMonths

```
    |id     |
    |Months |
```

TProduct1

```
  |id  |
  |RequestDay|
  |Mobile|
  |Operator|
  |Subjects|
  |OccurrenceMode|
  |Detective|
  |Months|
```

TProduct2

```
  |id  |
  |RequestDay|
  |Mobile|
  |Operator|
  |Subjects|
  |OccurrenceMode|
  |Detective|
  |Months|
```

TProduct3

```
  |id  |
  |RequestDay|
  |Mobile|
  |Operator|
  |Subjects|
  |OccurrenceMode|
  |Detective|
  |Months|
```

My SQL query looks like this:

```
select
    TDetective.Detective,
    count(TProduct1.id) as countOfDetectiveP1
    count(TProduct2.id) as countOfDetectiveP2
    count(TProduct3.id) as countOfDetectiveP3
from
    TDetective
left outer join  
    TProduct1 on TDetective.Detective = TProduct1.Detective
where 
    TProduct1.Months in (select months from TMonths)
left outer join 
    TProduct2 on TDetective.Detective = TProduct2.Detective
where 
    TProduct2.Months in (select months from TMonths)
left outer join 
    TProduct3 on TDetective.Detective = TProduct3.Detective
where 
    TProduct3.Months in (select months from TMonths)
group by
    Detective.Detective
order by 
    Detective
```

Many thanks

Comment: Replace `where` with `and` .

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

```
select d.Detective,
       (select count(*)
        from P118 p1
        where p1.detective = d.Detective and
              p1.Months in (select months from TempMonths)
       ),
       (select count(*)
        from P119 p2
        where p2.detective = d.Detective and
              p2.Months in (select months from TempMonths)
       ),
       (select count(*)
        from P120 p3
        where p3.detective = d.Detective and
              p3.Months in (select months from TempMonths)
       )
from Detective d 
order by Detective
```

Answer (score 0):

I would cross join the first two tables to get a row for every detective and month.  Then use correlated subqueries to fill in the rest of the information:

```
select d.id, d.month,
       (select count(*)
        from product1 p1
        where p1.detective = d.id and
              p1.month = m.month
       ),
       (select count(*)
        from product2 p2
        where p2.detective = d.id and
              p2.month = m.month
       ),
       (select count(*)
        from product3 p3
        where p3.detective = d.id and
              p3.month = m.month
       )
from detective d cross join
     months m;
```

You can add a `where` clause to the outer query to filter for particular detectives or months.